# What is an efficient data type for storing a 32-byte hash value?

Tags: postgresql

I understand that I can use a varchar(64) to hold the hex representation of the 32 bytes, but I imagine a `bytea` would be half the size, plus overhead. Are there any gotchas with `bytea`, or any more efficient way of storing the 32 bytes?

Comment: http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2008/09/working-with-bitstrings-in-postgresql.html

Comment: What's your priority? Ease of use? low storage space on-disk? Indexable? Space-efficient wire representation? There are different approaches with different trade-offs (including custom types) so it'd help to know what's important for your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest issue with bytea is that decoding it on the client takes extra memory in most frameworks.  This is probably not a big issue.  It has a more efficient on-disk representation though.

As Craig noted in the comment the best type for this depends to a fair degree on what you are doing with it.  I tend towards varchar because it is easiest to work with.  bytea would work also however,  and would save some disk space.